# jQuery Adding Class on Selected Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I am a beginner with jQuery and I am trying to modify a script. The script demo is [here](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/01/sweet-tabs-jquery-ajax-css/demo.html).  Right now, they add a line above the selected tab, which I don't want.  What I want to do is just add a class to the anchor like a

```
<a class="tab active" href="#">Tab Name</a>
```

that way I can just use CSS to change the background color or something for the active buttons.

The code below is what they currently have for when you click on a tab.

```
the_tabs.click(function(e){
    /* "this" points to the clicked tab hyperlink: */
    var element = $(this);

    /* If it is currently active, return false and exit: */
    if(element.hasClass('.active')) return false;

    $(this).addClass('active')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
the_tabs.click(function(e){
    var element = $(this);
    if( element.hasClass('active') ) {
        return false;
    }
    else {   
        the_tabs.removeClass('active'); 
        element.addClass('active');
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, please mark as answered when you get the time :-)

Answer (score 2):

You just need:

```
 $(this).addClass('nameOfYourClass')
```

to add a class to the clicked object

Comment: Actually, I think I got it!  Except it never goes away once clicked.  How do I remove it when it is clicked off?  Updated my code with what I have so far.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
if(element.find('.active').length) return false;
```

use

```
if(element.hasClass('.active')) return false;
```

or you have to use `.filter` instead of `.find`, find is trying to find a child node that has the class .active but `.filter` filters out the collection to find the matching css-selecotr

Comment: Thank you. so where do I put the function to remove the class if clicked away?  my only problem right now is that when I click on a tab, it turns active but when I click the next one, the other one stays active so now they both are. And it keeps going.

Comment: sure the_tabs.not(this).removeClass(".active") should do it? if the_tabs are all of your tabs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
the_tabs.click(function(e){
    /* "this" points to the clicked tab hyperlink: */
    var element = $(this);

    /* If it is currently active, return false and exit: */
    if(element.hasClass('active')) return false;

    /* Detecting the color of the tab (it was added to the class attribute in the loop above): */
    var bg = element.attr('class').replace('tab ','');

    $('ul.tabContainer .active').removeClass('active');
    element.addClass('active');

    /* Checking whether the AJAX fetched page has been cached: */

    if(!element.data('cache'))
    {   
        /* If no cache is present, show the gif preloader and run an AJAX request: */
        $('#contentHolder').html('<img src="img/ajax_preloader.gif" width="64" height="64" class="preloader" />');

        $.get(element.data('page'),function(msg){
            $('#contentHolder').html(msg);

            /* After page was received, add it to the cache for the current hyperlink: */
            element.data('cache',msg);
        });
    }
    else $('#contentHolder').html(element.data('cache'));

    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Also check my blog (website) for some nice jQuery guides. :)